# how to log only flask logs to a file - python

Tags: python

I'm using flask and I'm trying to log `werkzueg` logs

so i tried to set a file, simply it worked, but the problem is

some other logs are getting into the file, other libraries logs, which i don't want to happen

i tried to look it up but i didn't find anything helpful

here's my code :

i tried :

```
logging.basicConfig(file="myapp.log")
```

results :
other logs getting involved

anything will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using [`basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig). If you don't want a basic config, then don't call it.

Set up your [handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#handler-objects) explicitely on a specific [logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects), identified by its name.

See also : [the official How-To for the logging library](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)